UIStackView change distribution from fill to fillEqually confusingly

As the picture :

My Inner StackView (horizontal) set distribution to fill
When you add two labels to this inner stackview , these two
labels will got the same width . seems the distribution is set to
fillEqually.

This is very confusing. And I can't found any material about why the UIStackView make this change .
Is this a undocumented feature or just a bug of UIStackView?
##########update############
seems a interface builder bug. After I reset all my xib contents ,and  rebuild them again as before , this problem will not happen , and the ambiguous error will be generated as expeced

You keep asking the same question... "I design an ambiguous layout, and I want to know how auto-layout will resolve it." You would be much better off designing non-ambiguous layouts.

YES , I was hope to know the rule  to better design the layout . otherwise it's so common to design an ambiguous layout like this: a VerticalStackView contains Two Top-aligned HorizontalStack. with so many different behaves based on each HorizontalStack's subview counts

Don’t ask: how will an ambiguous layout be resolved. Instead, design the layout and apply constraints (and other properties) to achieve your layout goal. In none of your three questions have you described what layout you want.

I have described the layout  : a Verticle Stack View contains Two Top Aligned Horizontal Stack View , If both of HStack contains one label , it's ambiguous as expeced,But if one HStack contains one label , the other HStackcontains two label , ambiguous is disappear which is not understandable , I want to know how to make this kind of ambigous fix , and I think the two label should not make the ambiguous disappear ,so I want to know how the ambiguous disappear when the Horizontal StackView 's subview counts changed

That’s my point… you’ve designed an ambiguous layout, and you’re trying to figure out what will happen to it. My question is: what do you want to happen? Do you want the top HStack to stay at the top, and the bottom HStack to stay at the bottom? Do you want the top HStack to be the height of its subviews and the bottom HStack to fill the rest? Do you want the top HStack to fill down to the bottom HStack? Something else?

@DonMag , I can accept this layout is ambiguous , the thing I can't understand is the ambiguous is disappearing when you add one more label to one HStack , because add one more label seems has nothing to do with fixing ambiguous

@DonMag , I think all of your questions should be exist still after I adding  one more label to one HStack , so the ambiguous should be exist still , but the ambiguous is disappear after adding one label

So you're still just throwing UI elements on the screen, and wondering why you sometimes get a Red indicator and sometimes you don't. But you still haven't told me what layout you want. If you're not actually trying to learn the correct way to use auto-layout, then you should probably delete all three of these questions.

@DonMag, I know how to avoid this kind of problem , I just wanna know why this problem is happen , can you give me a reasonable explanation why the UIStackView layout is different based on different subview count ? or simply , why the ambiguous is disappear after one more label added

I think stackoverflow is not only a place to fix problem but also a place to know why, hopes a guy knows how UIStackView layout internals may answer those questiones someday

sigh ... Here's my comment from one of your other questions: ximmyxiao - I've pointed you to Apple's docs which state both A) "When an ambiguous layout occurs at runtime, Auto Layout chooses one of the possible solutions"; and B) "Interface Builder ... cannot find all possible layout errors.". -- and I provided a screen-recording video - https://i.imgur.com/o1f7Rhu.mp4 - showing how you can make IB get rid of the Red indicator without making any layout changes, and how to bring it back simply be changing a background color...

If you want Top HStack to fit its views and stay at the top, and Bottom HStack to fit its views and stay at the bottom, you've laid it out incorrectly. If you want Top to fit its views, and Bottom to "stretch," you've laid it out incorrectly. If you want Bottom to fit its views, and Top to "stretch,", you've laid it out incorrectly. If you want some other layout, again, you've laid it out incorrectly. If you don't care how the views get laid out, well... congratulations!!! you've completed your task.

Thanks @DonMag ,I have said that I have no problem to fix this layout to do anything as I wanted . The only reason I post these questions is I wanna know the mechanism behind , don't you think the ambiguous's disappearing after you add a Label to one HStack is hard to understand ?

No, I don’t find it hard to understand. Apple’s docs state: "Interface Builder ... cannot find all possible layout errors." I would never rely on IB alone - particularly when we can easily show that IB can be fooled into thinking the layout has no errors.

They are filling the space equally because they have the same compression resistance and content hugging priorities. By assigning a higher priority to one, you'll see them fill their parent unequally, as you likely expected.
You can access these properties from the size inspector panel:


But the same  compression resistance and content hugging priorities cause ambiguous layout in most times ,because the UIStackView can't know whom to shrink& stretch. If you put the Horizontal StackView outside (not embed in a Vertical StackView), those two label will cause a layout error, and not fill equally

In fact , after I remove  all the content， and re-construct the xib, the ambiguous layout error will be generated as expect , the fillEqually will not happed ... I'am going crazy..
